# Revising Code to add columns and change header names

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns

I "inherited" this code from a previous colleague at my company and need to revise it. I am not at that level of programming that I can make sense of some the lines.

The code right now works. It compares two sheets with identical headers and identical A/B/C column information. All other cells are #s and can change.

 
 1. Sheet 1/Origin compared to Sheet 2/Current 
 2. lists the value of each column from each sheet next to eachother and 
 3. calculates the % deviation. 
 so each block in the result sheet has 3 columns per identical column.

[image]

The previous code however used a result table with pre-named headers and only after column 12 would it use whatever the headers are named in the original sheets. Right now Columns are simple named Column 1,2,3 etc.

I am trying to make two additions to this:

1. add a column calculation where value difference (current - origin) is calculated. Column to be called Deviation #. I already added an ElseIf condition in the code but it doesn't calculate and the additional column only shows up at the end of the table but not per block.

[image] 
2.  and I would like the result table to use the same headers starting in Column A Lane ID, Origin Region etc from the source sheets, as it does right now from Column 12 on. (sample below; starting with Random 1)

this is the code:

```
Sub Changes()
Dim x, y, z, Hdrs, i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Long
x = Original.UsedRange
y = Current.UsedRange
ReDim z(1 To UBound(x, 1) - 1, 1 To UBound(x, 2) * 3 - 6)
ReDim Hdrs(1 To UBound(z, 2) - 11)
x(1, 2) = "Origin Region": x(1, 3) = "Origin Country"

For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    For ii = 1 To 3
        z(i - 1, ii) = x(i, ii)
    Next
Next
For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    iii = 1
    For ii = 4 To UBound(x, 2)
        iii = iii + 3
        z(i - 1, iii) = x(i, ii): z(i - 1, iii + 1) = y(i, ii)
        If x(i, ii) = 0 Or IsEmpty(x(i, ii)) Then
            z(i - 1, iii + 2) = "New Entry"
         ElseIf x(i, ii) <> 0 Then
            z(i - 1, iii + 2) = Format(y(i, ii) / x(i, ii) - 1, "0%")
         ElseIf x(i, ii) <> 0 Then
            z(i - 1, iii + 3) = Format(y(i, ii) - x(i, ii) - 1, "0")
        End If
    Next
Next
ii = -2
For i = 7 To UBound(x, 2)
    ii = ii + 3
    Hdrs(ii) = x(1, i) & " Original"
    Hdrs(ii + 1) = x(1, i) & " Current"
    Hdrs(ii + 2) = x(1, i) & " Deviation %"
    Hdrs(ii + 3) = x(1, i) & " Deviation #"
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
With Result.ListObjects(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    .DataBodyRange.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Parent.Columns(13).Resize(, 50).Delete
    For i = .ListColumns.Count To 13 Step -1
        .ListColumns(i).Delete
    Next
    .Parent.[a3].Resize(UBound(z, 1), UBound(z, 2)) = z
    .Parent.[m2].Resize(, UBound(Hdrs)) = Hdrs
    
    'You will probably have to adjust the ColumnWidth value in the next line
    'to suit your actual extra headers
    .Parent.[m2].Resize(, UBound(Hdrs)).ColumnWidth = 10

End With
```

End Sub

[image]

Origin Sheet Example:
[image]

Comment: solution in case of interested parties

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Changes()
Dim x, y, z, Hdrs, i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Long
x = Original.UsedRange
y = Current.UsedRange
ReDim z(1 To UBound(x, 1) - 1, 1 To UBound(x, 2) * 4 - 9)
ReDim Hdrs(1 To UBound(z, 2))

For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    For ii = 1 To 3
        z(i - 1, ii) = x(i, ii)
    Next
Next
For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    iii = 0
    For ii = 4 To UBound(x, 2)
        iii = iii + 4
        z(i - 1, iii) = x(i, ii): z(i - 1, iii + 1) = y(i, ii)
        If x(i, ii) = 0 Or IsEmpty(x(i, ii)) Then
            z(i - 1, iii + 2) = "New Entry"
            If iii = UBound(z, 2) - 3 Then Exit For
         Else
            z(i - 1, iii + 2) = Format(z(i - 1, iii + 1) - z(i - 1, iii), "0.00")
            z(i - 1, iii + 3) = Format(z(i - 1, iii + 1) / z(i - 1, iii) - 1, "0%")
        End If
    Next
Next
For i = 1 To 3
    Hdrs(i) = x(1, i)
Next
ii = 0
For i = 4 To UBound(x, 2)
    ii = ii + 4
    Hdrs(ii) = x(1, i) & " Original"
    Hdrs(ii + 1) = x(1, i) & " Current"
    Hdrs(ii + 2) = x(1, i) & " Deviation #"
    Hdrs(ii + 3) = x(1, i) & " Deviation %"
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
With DataChanges
    With .ListObjects(1)
        On Error Resume Next
        .DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Parent.Columns(4).Resize(, 100).Delete
        .Resize .HeaderRowRange.Columns(1).Resize(UBound(z, 1) + 1, UBound(z, 2))
        .DataBodyRange = z
        .HeaderRowRange = Hdrs
        For i = 4 To UBound(Hdrs) - 3 Step 8
            .HeaderRowRange.Columns(i).Resize(, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(84, 130, 53)
        Next
        With .DataBodyRange
            For i = 4 To UBound(Hdrs) - 3 Step 8
                For ii = 1 To .Rows.Count Step 2
                    .Columns(i).Rows(ii).Resize(, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142)
                Next
                For ii = 2 To .Rows.Count - 1 Step 2
                    .Columns(i).Rows(ii).Resize(, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 224, 180)
                Next
            Next
        End With
    End With
    .Columns(4).Resize(, UBound(Hdrs) + 1).ColumnWidth = 12
End With
```

End Sub